# Automatically Adjust UIView's Height to It's Subview using AutoLayout (Storyboard)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uitextfield, autolayout

I am using StoryBoards and Autolayout.

Below is the hierarchy:

```
- Superview
-- UIView (ContentView)
--- UITextField
--- UITextField
--- UITextField
--- UITextField
```

The UIView(ContentView)'s is constrained to Left, Top, Right of the SuperView with the offset of 20;

The Bottom of UIView(ContentView) is not constrained to anything.

I would like the contentView's height adjusted based on how many textField in it. Any thoughts how I could achieve this using AutoLayout?

I am very new in Autolayout. Used to do all UI in code.

Any thoughts?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silly me, found the answer, I simply restrict the height of all the subviews and then constraint the most bottom of the bottom subview to the UIView/ContentView