# AutoLayout: how to constrain UIView to be no taller than the height needed to contain all its subviews?

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, autolayout, uistoryboard

There are a few answers on SO that seem to address the same question, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30408625/automatically-adjust-uiviews-height-to-its-subview-using-autolayout-storyboar). However, none of these worked.

The goal is to use AutoLayout and Storyboard to create a UIView, call it `parentView`, that is tall enough to contain its subviews and no taller.

This can easily be done in code, but the goal is to do it all within Storyboard with AutoLayout constraints and without having to specify a static height (e.g., assume one of the subviews is a UILabel so `parentView` would need to grow correspondingly if the UILabel's height grows because of long text).

Is this possible?

Comment: Are we assuming there can be multiple subviews?

Comment: its absolutely possible and can be achieved by setting up the constraints properly :)

Comment: @HaydenHolligan yes assume there are multiple subviews!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can actually be accomplished not with the addition of constraints, but the lack thereof!

Drag a new `View` into the superview and give it two constraints: Center X and Center Y. Drag some views/labels and add them to the `View`.

In order for this to work, the subviews inside must have constraints to the leading/trailing/top/bottom of the `View` holding everything together. This "defines" constraints for the `View's` width and height so XCode doesn't get mad at you.

That's it. [Example project.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jurrp7rys8eiuds/AADh4FkpEnTX-eyql6z9MHX6a?dl=0)

Edit: Image of the view and constraints
[image]

Comment: Thanks will download the example project but for future readers who may not have Dropbox, when you said `drag a new view into the superview`, is "new view" `parentView` or is that "superview"? If it's the former, that was tried and didn't work?

Comment: new view is a literal new "View" from the object library. I reference the superview as the main view for the view controller. I edited the answer for some clarification.

Comment: OK so "new view" is what is referred to as `parentView` in the question. Thanks! Your method works (tested in example project), not sure why it's not working for us, though. Xcode continues to complain about needing a height for `parentView` (or new view) even though we've given it the `Center X` and `Center Y` constraints. Will mark this as correct nonetheless.

Comment: Glad to help! It might be related to your constraints with the subviews inside the `parentView`. The subviews kind of "define" the height and width of the `parentView` with the leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. We used "Center Y" for one of the subviews, but we had to use top & bottom constraints instead. So for future readers, the trick is to make sure each subview uses top/bottom/leading/trailing constraints. Cannot use "Center X" or "Center Y."